# Convert minutes into datetime in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame as below

```
customerid  mydate
123         15:11.01
234         42:34.04
234         39:35.01
```

I have df with mixed timestamps example

```
customerid            mydate

    123              2016-08-15 18:22:40
    234              2017-08-15 42:34.04
    234              39:35.01
```

mydate is a null object and I want to convert it into date time. I used the below

```
df['mydate'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['mydate'], format='%M:%S')
```

I get the error below

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .0
```

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: keyError Only throw when you are trying to access undefined column, may be your column name contains spaces

Comment: @jezrael ['customerid', 'mydate']

Comment: @jezrael                                                                                                            
I df with mixed timestamps example                                                          
customer id  mydate
123              2016-08-15 18:22:40
234              2017-08-15 42:34.04
234              39:35.01

Comment: Sorry, I was offline, but now add answer to your last question.